# Prining newlines embedded in string

Tags: node.js, linux

From a websocket I'm getting this data which I'm printing  using `console.log` on a Linux console(using putty):

```
{"report":"IP Report:\n35.194.173.178:1"}
```

I want it to create a newline whereever "`\n`" is there in the string. How to achieve this?

Comment: For `console.log("IP Report:\n35.194.173.178:1")`, node.js will print with line break. Can you provide more detail?

Answer (score 0):

What you're getting here is a JSON string. You need to parse it using `JSON.parse()` (inside a `try`/`catch` block because it can throw an exception on bad input - or you can use my [`tryjson`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tryjson) module).

When you parse it you'll get an object whose `report` property is the string that you need to print.

Simplest example:

```
const obj = JSON.parse(yourData);
console.log(obj.report);
```

but make sure to add error handling:

```
try {
  const obj = JSON.parse(yourData);
  console.log(obj.report);
} catch (err) {
  // handle the error
}
```

Comment: If obj.report contains a string with "\n" then it is not printing a line break in the putty. How to make it print new line?